# An error occurs when using the moveByTransporter AnyLogik component

Tags: anylogic

I'm trying to use the TransporterFleet and moveByTransporter components. When I select the navigation type "Arbitrary movement", there are no problems. If I select "By specified paths", the error Path not found occurs! {agent=1, source={level=level, pos=(700.0, 560.0009999999999, 0.0)}, target={level=level, pos=(700.0, 350.0, 0.0, 1.5707963267948966, -0.0)}}. I can't figure out what the problem is.

I tried different destinations. There is always an error.

Comment: show a picture on when the error occurs with origin a destination

Comment: There is not enough rating to send an image. But I think I've figured out the problem. I wanted to get the agent moving along the same line in both directions. When I closed the contour, the agent began to move freely along the contour. It seems that a different solution is needed for my task.